# How to run pm2 on server restarts?

Tags: pm2

**I want to run pm2 not server restarts but it not working, where mkdir working perfectly**

**server os :** ubuntu 18.04

**myscirpt.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for the system to fully initialize
sleep 30

# Change to the node directory
cd /var/www/html/node/sms-management-system
/usr/bin/pm2 start app.js --name "SMS" -o ./sms.log -e ./sms.log --merge-logs
/usr/bin/pm2 save

cd /var/www/html/React/sms-management-system
/usr/bin/pm2 start npm -- start --name "React-Sms" -o ./react_sms_O.log -e ./react_sms_E.log --merge-logs
/usr/bin/pm2 save

# Start the PM2 service
/usr/bin/pm2 startup ubuntu

# Change to the html directory
cd /var/www/html/
mkdir ererere

# Save the PM2 configuration again to include the new process
/usr/bin/pm2 save
```

Comment: *"but it not working"* is not a proper problem description ... Do you have any logs/error messages? I never used pm2 but `/usr/bin/pm2 start npm` might be a problem because for this to work `npm` probably has to be in the path of the current runtime environment,which might not be the case ...

Comment: Okay, I have changes to `/usr/bin/pm2 start "npm start" --name "React-Sms" -o ./react_sms_O.log -e ./react_sms_E.log --merge-logs`, and this is my log `> sms@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start`. @derpirscher